# How to make Redis slave read only in Redis v2.4.6?

Tags: redis, replication, master-slave

I used slave-read-only yes in `redis.conf` file.

```
CONFIG SET "slave-read-only" "yes"
(error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: slave-read-only
```

How to set the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/replication#read-only-slave):

> **Since Redis 2.6**, slaves support a read-only mode that is enabled by default. This behavior is controlled by the `slave-read-only` option in the redis.conf file, and can be enabled and disabled at runtime using CONFIG SET.

For any Redis version earlier than 2.6, `slave-read-only` parameter was not available (and thus not recognized). So, in Redis v2.4.6, you will not be able to set that parameter.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response. What can be the latest version to be installed in Windows system. Any links?

Comment: Windows 10: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/ ; Windows 8.1 (and lower): https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-8-1-and-previous-versions/

Comment: Thanks alot. One more concern. When my slave initiates a telnet to my master server , it connects. And its able to modify / flush my data. How to control the same?

Comment: Don't know. PS: you can accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks alot sazzad. It was very useful.